# "Control variable "i" is modified"

Tags: java, checkstyle, bluej

Here is my code, my problem is with `function tubes.remove(i--)`. It is a checkstyle error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tubes.size(); i++) {
    Rectangle rect = tubes.get(i);
    rect.x -= spd;

    if (rect.x + 40  <= 0) {
        tubes.remove(i--);
        Hra.getHrac1().setSkore(0.5);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you add what error you are getting ?

Comment: That is a warning about the automatically incremented control variable `i` gets *manually* decremented by `i--` in `tubes.remove(i--)`, make it `tubes.remove(i - 1)`.

Comment: Please include error log, if you are getting any

Comment: @Nicolas that's not correct, because `remove` decreases `size()` by 1. You cannot have an infinite loop which removes an item from a list on every iteration without putting a new item in to replace it.

Comment: @Nicolas also `i--` is not the same as `i = i - 1` in an expression, because the value of `i--` is the value of `i` before the decrement, whereas the value of `i = i - 1` is the value after the decrement.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, Checkstyle is warning you that this *could be* a mistake. But actually it is not a logical mistake in your algorithm; `i--` does decrease the value of `i`, but `tubes.remove(i--)` also decreases `tubes.size()`, so the difference `tubes.size() - i` remains unchanged by this operation. Therefore the loop does terminate.

The suggestion by @deHaar is actually **incorrect**, for two reasons.

- Firstly, `i - 1` and `i--` never have the same value, because `i--`'s value is the original value of `i` before decrementing. If you do `tubes.remove(i - 1)` then it will not remove the current list element; it will remove the list element *before* the current one, which is not the correct one to remove.
- Secondly, when you remove an element at index `i`, the next element you want to check will move from index `i + 1` to index `i` to "fill in the gap" left by the element you removed. If you don't decrement `i`, then the next index you look at will be `i + 1`; effectively, you will skip over the next element from the list, so if there are two elements in a row which need to be removed, your loop would only remove one element. The `i--` is necessary so that you look at index `i` again after this, because that's where the next list element will be after removing the current one.

That said, while `tubes.remove(i--)` is not a logical error, it is certainly a style error. Two experienced programmers have looked at your code and thought it is wrong. That means your code is too tricky for an experienced programmer to read it and reliably work out what it does, so it should be re-written in a clearer way.

Here are two clearer ways to re-write your code:

### 1. Iterate backwards

If `i` goes from the end of the list to the start, then the `remove` method will only shift around elements you've already looked at. The next index to look at will be `i - 1` whether or not you remove the current element, so there is no need to update `i` when you remove an element.

```java
for (int i = tubes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // iterate backwards
    Rectangle rect = tubes.get(i);
    rect.x -= spd;

    if (rect.x + 40 <= 0) {
        tubes.remove(i); // no need to change i here
        Hra.getHrac1().setSkore(0.5);
    }
}
```

### 2. Remove using an `Iterator`

Removing elements from a list you're currently iterating over is tricky to get right, especially if you're removing them by index. On the other hand, if you explicitly iterate over the list using an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) then you don't need to use an index variable at all, and the iterator has a convenient [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method, which won't mess up the iteration for later elements in the list.

```java
for (Iterator<Rectangle> iter = tubes.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Rectangle rect = iter.next();
    rect.x -= spd;

    if (rect.x + 40 <= 0) {
        iter.remove();
        Hra.getHrac1().setSkore(0.5);
    }
}
```

Note that I've removed the `continue` from both solutions as this has no effect at the end of the loop body anyway.